# Null timestamp in database - Carbon

Tags: laravel, timestamp

I have a problem with the storage of zero date in the MySql database in the field of type timestamp. To read this field I use the Carbon library. When the value in database is equal 0000-00-00 00-00-00 Carbon converts it into a -0001-11-30 0:00:00. When saving to use a NULL value for the timestamp field. If I check if a date field is empty I must compare it to -0001-11-30 0:00:00. How can I solve this problem? Thank You!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have created the tables using `migration` then for the date filed use `nullable` method to allow `null` value as default, for example:

```
$table->timestamp('dateFieldName')->nullable();
```

If you created the table using a differnt way then make sure that null value is allowed as default. Check [this nice answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51748/why-does-mysql-adds-a-default-timestamp-on-insert-update-even-if-i-did-not-speci) here for more information.